# Question regarding order of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given any positive integer $n$, characterize all positive integers $m$ such that there is an invertible $n×n$ matrix with rational entries whose order is $m$. Honestly I have been trying to answer this question but can't find any proper characterization, so any help or hint will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "order" of matrix is $m$? Are you referring to $A^m=I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m$ be a positive integer that factors as $m=\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{m_i}$, where the $p_i$ are distinct primes and the $m_i$ are positive integers.

If $A$ is an invertible $n\times n$-matrix with rational entries whose order is $m$, then $A^m=I$ and so its minimal polynomial divides $x^m-1$. This polynomial factors as a product of cyclotomic polynomials, i.e.
$$x^m-1=\prod_{d\mid m}\Phi_d,$$
so the minimal polynomial of $A$ is a product of distinct cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_d$ with $d\mid m$. Moreover, because the order of $A$ is precisely $m$, the least common multiple of these divisors must again be $m$. That is to say, if the minimal polynomial $m_A$ of $A$ is given by
$$m_A=\prod_{j=1}^\ell\Phi_{d_j}
\qquad\text{ so that }\qquad 
\deg m_A=\sum_{j=1}^\ell\varphi(d_j),$$
then we must have $\operatorname{lcm}\{d_1,\ldots,d_\ell\}=m$. It turns out that...

> ...if $\operatorname{lcm}\{d_1,\ldots,d_\ell\}=m=\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{m_i}$ then $\sum_{j=1}^\ell\varphi(d_j)\geq\sum_{i=1}^k\varphi(p_i^{m_i})$.

From this it follows that
$$\deg m_A\geq\sum_{i=1}^k\varphi(p_i^{m_i})=\sum_{i=1}^kp_i^{m_i-1}(p_i-1).$$

On the other hand, by Cayley-Hamilton, the degree of the minimal polynomial of $A$ is at most $n$. So for an $n\times n$-matrix of order $m=\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{m_i}$ to exist we must have
$$\sum_{i=1}^kp_i^{m_i-1}(p_i-1)\leq n.$$

To see that this upper bound is sharp, you can simply take for $A$ the companion matrix of the polynomial
$$\prod_{i=1}^k\Phi_{p_i^{m_i}}.$$